# How to Start a Universal Windows App (UWP) with Environment Variables Programmatically?

Tags: node.js, windows, uwp, environment-variables

I am trying to launch a Universal Windows App (UWP) with environment variables using Node JS in Windows 10 and above.
I was able to successfully launch the app with the following command:
`exec("start shell:AppsFolder\{PACKAGE_FAMILY_NAME}!{APP_ID} <params>", { env });` but the environment variables do not seem to be set when I try to read them from the UWP app.

`shell:appsfolder` is a shortcut for `explorer.exe shell:::{"Applications Folder CLSID Key"}`, It seems that the environment variables are not passed to the explorer application.

I also tried to pass the parameters using `<command> /k set key=value` with no luck.

Any idea how to solve this issue?

---

[1] Windows [start](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/start) command.

[2] Node JS [exec](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_processexeccommand-options-callback) command.

Comment: UWP apps run in an isolated 'AppContainer' context, so you can't set environment variables for them in 'real world' scenarios.

Comment: Do you control the code that reads the environment variable[s]? Or is it a 3rd-party component? Will the variable[s] always be the same, or do you need to change them dynamically?

Comment: The application that reads the environment variable[s] provides interactable python shell, I access them through it. The variables are dynamically set before each invocation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like @Chuck mentioned, it is not possible to set environment variables for UWP apps when you launch UWP apps. UWP apps are running in AppContainer in the sandbox and isolated from the system.